# Facebook Intersect Search does not work

Tags: facebook

The following search worked for me till 2 days ago and is not working any more:
https://www.facebook.com/search/str/Germany/liked/residents/present/str/France/pages-named/residents/past/intersect

Who can help me?

Comment: When I click on above link it gives this result: _Sorry, we couldn't understand this search. Please try saying this another way._
You may try in other way, or tell us exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to get persons - who live in Germany and lived in France. And this worked,....now not any more..

Comment: I think Facebook has changed the searching options. I didn't find any advance or refined search.

Answer (score 1):

Your first part to intersect doesn't seem to have the correct query. Your two inner queries are

- /str/Germany/**liked**/residents/present (Bad Query)
- /str/France/pages-named/residents/past/intersect

The query I think you want

https://www.facebook.com/search/str/Germany/pages-named/residents/present/str/France/pages-named/residents/past/intersect